# NServiceBus.IStartableBus is not registered in the container. NServiceBus 4.6.3

Tags: c#, ninject, nservicebus

I am attempting a very simple application with NServiceBus and Ninject.

I am attempting to use Ninject as the container for NServiceBus, but I am getting the following error - "NServiceBus.IStartableBus is not registered in the container."

I'm sure the answer is quite obvious... just not to me!

My code is as follows

```
public class StartApp : IWantCustomInitialization, IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    private static IKernel _kernel;
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Serialization.Json();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();

        Configure.With()
            .NinjectBuilder(_kernel)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();

        Bus.Send(new TestMessage {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), MessageText = "Bloop"});
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }
}
```

```
namespace NServiceBus_Ninject_Simple
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
    { }
}
```

Comment: what packages & versions are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/yDWc7LUMH1M) google groups discussion is about the same issue.

It seems you are creating the configuration in the wrong place.
It should look like this:

```
public abstract class DefaultEndpointConfig
    : IConfigureThisEndpoint
    , IWantCustomInitialization
{
  IWantCustomInitialization.Init()
  {
    Configure
      .With()
      .NinjectBuilder();
      // + any other config;

    // Call optional endpoint specific config
    Init();
  }

  public virtual void Init()
  {
  }
}
```

See [here (Johannes Gustafsson)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fjohannesg%2F6563373&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH2IRoRjpk0TCh7Z2p32WGH8uqgMw)

It needs to be done in the EndPoint-Configuration (for every endpoint, this is why he suggests using a base class) and it needs to implement `IConfigureThisEndpoint`.